# How do Symfony Flex recipes know what packages to install?

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-flex

I am trying to understand how Symfony recipes know what packages to install along the way.

Reading the source code, it seems to me that when I run

```
composer require twig
```

the composer, having flex as a plugin,

1. looks for an alias called *twig*
2. sees that it is registered for the recipe *symfony/twig-pack*
3. downloads the recipe and reads its manifest.json
4. executes all the actions defined in manifest.json, like creating extra files or appending stuff to files

But nowhere do I see in the manifest.json to install the *actual package* symfony/twig-pack.

Is it just implicit that *all* recipes **have** to share their name with the package they are installing and that this is the way how composer knows what package to install?

I.e. a developer can not just create a recipe *invented_company/nonexisting_package* that just adds a few files here and appends a few lines there, but not actually corresponds to a package on packagist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a description of the creation of recipes.

It says

> Recipes must be stored on their own repositories, outside of your Composer package repository. They must follow the vendor/package/version/ directory structure, where version is the minimum version supported by the recipe.

https://github.com/symfony/recipes/blob/master/README.rst

Comment: I had been reading exactly that documentation, but I interpreted the part you are mentioning being about naming, not about a 1-to-1 relationship between package and recipe. It would have been nice to include a "Flex will automatically install the package with the same name for you AND perform your recipe". But maybe that was clear from the beginning. Thanks for taking the time!